# Assigning two values to a variable

Tags: python, selenium

I will try and explain this as well as possible without giving too many details on what I'm trying to do.

I have a website `Website1` with a product `x` that has a value of 1
I have another website `Website2` with the same product `x` that has a value of 2.

The product "x" has two values that need to be paired. Does this happen using a tuple?

```
x = [1, 2]
```

On `Website2` I need to check a list of line items one by one in a loop. When it finds product `x` and it matches the joined value of 2 from `Website1` in the tuple, I need to then perform a function to change the fulfillment value, the move onto the next line item to perform the next check. Here's what I have so far and I'm not even certain if the logic is anywhere close.

```
x = [1, 2]

if Website1 == x:
LineItem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]/div/div/input').clear()
time.sleep(2)
LineItem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]/div/div/input').send_keys("1")

else:
LineItem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]/div/div/input').clear()
time.sleep(2)
LineItem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]/div/div/input').send_keys("0")
```

Comment: that's not a tuple

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can easily use tuples to assign two values to a variable (the entire tuple is being assigned to the variable):

```
x = (val1, val2)
x[0] == val1  # True
x[1] == val2  # True
```

Side note:
`[]` defines a list, not a tuple. The latter is the immutable variant of the former

Comment: Thank you. Is my logic correct in how to match them in the code I provided? I swapped out the braces for the parentheses and it's not finding a match in the "if" statement.

Comment: `if Website1 == x[0]` should work, if the first element of `x` is `Website1`

Answer (score 0):

You should use tuples.

```
x = (1, 2)
```

To get the values from tuples you simply do:

`x[0]` to get the first value, `x[1]` for the next and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a tuple but you don't have to. It's just one way to do it. What you have in `[]`s is an array. You can use that also and if you add a third+ website, you won't have to change the data structure, you'll just add a new value, e.g. `x = [1, 2, 3]` so having the array makes it easier to expand later vs a tuple.

Now to the code. It's kinda hard to understand your logic without more explanation but this should address your problem (and simplify your code).

You will notice that both the `if` and `else` block have basically the same code. The only difference is "1" vs "0" in the `send_keys()`. You should do some reading on [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) and DRY practices but the core concept is Don't Repeat Yourself. Pull the repeated lines out into a method called `set_fulfillment_value()` (You might want to give it a more appropriate name).

```
def set_fulfillment_value(value)
    LineItem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]/div/div/input').clear()
    # time.sleep(2) # this is a bad practice and should be removed (it likely isn't needed here anyway)
    LineItem.find_element_by_xpath('./td[4]/div/div/input').send_keys(value)
```

Use the `if` to set the value to be sent and then pass that into the method.

```
x = [1, 2]
value = None
if Website1 == x[0]:
    value = "1"
else:
    value = "0"
set_fulfillment_value(value)
```

---

NOTE: I know naming is hard but you should work on better variable names. `Website1` sounds like it might be better named something like `product`? Also, `LineItem` isn't very python-y. `line_item` would probably be better.

Answer (score 0):

```
myValues = (a, b, c)
```

This will create a tuple, in which you can store multiple values.
To get the different values, just use `myValues[0]` to get the first element, for example.